# How to come back to menu?

Tags: java

I am trying to create an issue tracking System, but I am having a bit of a problem, every time I run the code, it does not come back to the menu, it just loops. I want my code to come back to the menu whenever i describe my issue.

```
package com.company.TrackingSystem;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<TrackingSystem> tracker = new ArrayList<>();
        Main myApp = new Main();
        myApp.menu();
        System.out.print("Select option >> ");
        int option = in.nextInt();

        switch (option){
            case 1:
                myApp.CreateIssue(tracker);
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid choice...!");
                break;

        }
    }
    private ArrayList<TrackingSystem> CreateIssue(ArrayList<TrackingSystem> tracker){
        String issueCreator;
        String a = " ";
        boolean is = true;

        do {
            System.out.println("*** Create an Issue***");
            System.out.println("Describe your Issue: ");
            issueCreator = in.nextLine();


        }while (is);

        TrackingSystem ts = new TrackingSystem(issueCreator,false);
        tracker.add(ts);

        return tracker;
    }


    private void menu() {
        boolean is = true;

            System.out.println("---Menu---");
            System.out.println(
                    "1.Create new Issue\n" +
                            "2.Mark Issue as solved\n" +
                            "3.View unsolved Issues\n" +
                            "4.View solved Issues\n" +
                            "5.Exit\n"
            );

    }
}
```

**My tracking class**

```
package com.company.TrackingSystem;

public class TrackingSystem {
    private String createIssue;
    private boolean issueSolved;

    public TrackingSystem(String createIssue, boolean issueSolved) {
        this.createIssue = createIssue;
        this.issueSolved = issueSolved;
    }

    public String getCreateIssue() {
        return createIssue;
    }

    public void setCreateIssue(String createIssue) {
        this.createIssue = createIssue;
    }

    public boolean isIssueSolved() {
        return issueSolved;
    }

    public void setIssueSolved(boolean issueSolved) {
        this.issueSolved = issueSolved;
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
---Menu---
1.Create new Issue
2.Mark Issue as solved
3.View unsolved Issues
4.View solved Issues
5.Exit

Select option >> 1
*** Create an Issue***
Describe your Issue: 
*** Create an Issue***
Describe your Issue: 
as
*** Create an Issue***
Describe your Issue: 
sa
*** Create an Issue***
Describe your Issue: 
as
```

Comment: `while(is)` The value of `is` never changes in the loop

Comment: Was going to say the same, the `do{...}while(is);` in `CreateIssue` obviously is never updated, so it just has to loop.  (Also, please follow Java naming conventions, should be `createIssue`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at this function:

```
private ArrayList<TrackingSystem> CreateIssue(ArrayList<TrackingSystem> tracker){
    String issueCreator;
    String a = " ";
    boolean is = true;

    do {
        System.out.println("*** Create an Issue***");
        System.out.println("Describe your Issue: ");
        issueCreator = in.nextLine();


    }while (is);

    TrackingSystem ts = new TrackingSystem(issueCreator,false);
    tracker.add(ts);

    return tracker;
}
```

Pay special attention to the loop condition: `while(is)`. You declare `bool is = true;` but you never change it to false inside the loop. This means the loop will continue forever.

To fix this, you have to make some decisions. First, do you really want to continue looping here? Is your intention to allow the user to enter as many issues as they want? Or do you want to create only a single issue then return to the menu. If the former, then you need to figure out how the user will tell the program that they are finished entering issues. You can use this to stop the loop. If the later, then just remove the loop.

Now let's look at `main()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<TrackingSystem> tracker = new ArrayList<>();
    Main myApp = new Main();
    myApp.menu();
    System.out.print("Select option >> ");
    int option = in.nextInt();

    switch (option){
        case 1:
            myApp.CreateIssue(tracker);
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid choice...!");
            break;

    }
}
```

Even after you solve the problem with your code to create an issue, you will run the program and it will exit after one action. This is because you do not loop in `main()`. You need to add a loop here that repeats the following steps:

1. Print the menu.
2. Get the user's choice.
3. Perform the action for that choice
4. Repeat to step 1.

Each of these steps can be a method so that you can keep `main()` very short. Note how the first 3 steps are inside a loop. I think this is what you were trying to do with the loop for creating a new item, but somehow put the loop in the wrong place. As you can see here, by writing out the steps in words, we get a clear idea of how to organize the code. Doing this is a great tool when writing a computer program.